# SDL Mouse event not working

Tags: c++, mouseevent, sdl

When I declare Button class above the int main, I get the right results, but when create a new class Button, the mouse coordinates are wrong.
Here is my code:

```
class Button {
    public:
    SDL_Rect box;
    Button(int a, int b, int w, int h);
    Button(const Button& orig);
    virtual ~Button();
    void handle_events();
};

SDL_Event event1;

Button::Button(int x, int y, int w, int h) {
    //Set the button's attributes
    box.x = x;
    box.y = y;
    box.w = w;
    box.h = h;
}
void Button::handle_events() {

                    //Get the mouse offsets

                    int aa = event1.motion.x;
                    int bb = event1.motion.y;
                    printf("%d %d\n",aa,bb);
//...
}
..........
..........
SDL_Event event;
int main(){
Button test(431, 318, 81, 27);
if (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
play.handle_events();
}
return 0;
}
```

The output in stdout.txt:
0      0
431 318
0      0
and so on.
It should return current x,y of the mouse and not the first two arguments of the Button constructor?

Comment: You define one event called "event1" but use one called "event", but it's impossible to tell whether it's a bug or a typo.

Comment: *I forgot to edit event above int main.

Answer (score 1):

`Button::handle_events()` uses a different variable from the one you're passing to `SDL_PollEvent` - even the names are different.
I'm not sure why would expect changes to one of them to affect the other.

Why don't you pass it to the function, and avoid all the mess of global variables:

```
void Button::handle_events(SDL_Event evt) {
    //Get the mouse offsets
    int aa = evt.motion.x;
    int bb = evt.motion.y;
    printf("%d %d\n",aa,bb);
}


// ...

if (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
    play.handle_events(event);
}
```

(I assume the fact that you're defining "test", but using "play" in `main` is a typo.)